# does emacs calc support matrix eigenvalue decompose?

Tags: calc

I want to use emacs's calc to get the eigenvalue and eigenvector of a matrix.

I went to google but can't find anything about emacs and eigenvalue.

So, is calc support calculating eigenvalue or maybe it's a wrong try?

Comment: Maybe use [GNU octave](https://octave.org/) instead?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Under [TODO](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9d866a1f8da870dcf82f87d5ed9d5ca932d5477b/lisp/calc/calc.el#L47) , [calc.el#L69](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9d866a1f8da870dcf82f87d5ed9d5ca932d5477b/lisp/calc/calc.el#L69) says,

> **How about matrix eigenvalues, SVD, pseudo-inverse, etc.?** Should cache matrix inverses as well as decompositions. If dividing by a non-square matrix, use least-squares automatically. Consider supporting matrix exponentials.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that’s something that you’ll need to write yourself.

Comment: got it, thanks.